# jQuery dialog modal with asp.net mvc5 not supported

Tags: jquery, asp.net

so i'm trying to get a pop up dialog using jQuery popup modal 
in _Layout view I charged all the scripts needed

```html
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 300,
            height: 250,
        });
    });
</script>
```

So in the View where it's supposed to be :

```html
<body>
    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">

    </div>
</body>
```

and this is my bundle config file

```html
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/datepicker.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

Comment: first of all remove `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>` and `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3.js"></script>`. you can't take both min and dev version of jquery

Comment: I did it but still not working for me

Comment: Did you add css file refrence?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />`

Comment: I'm having object dialog is not supported any idea ? please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem so here is what i did
first in the head section

```html
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    
    <script>
       $(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 300,
                height: 250,
                
            });

            $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        function onSuccess() {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
        }
       
    </script>
```

and in the View where i want my pop up

```html
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the theme css file, check this example
http://jsbin.com/ruhegijayu/1/

Comment: I have a question has it to be in the head section ?

Comment: The script references and stylesheets yes

Comment: you could have referenced jQuery multiple times

Comment: I'm having object dialog is not supported any idea ? please @Tarek